# After getting all the filepaths of a top folder, how can I write them all to a new file?

Tags: python, loops, file-io, file-writing, os.walk

I would like to write all the filepaths to a new text file. My code only writes the last filepath rather than all of filepaths as I would like it to.
Why is it doing this ?; What can I do to get all the joined filepaths written to a new text file?

My code:

```
for directoryPath, subDirectory, files in os.walk('Y:\folderName'): 
    for file in files: 
        joined = os.path.join(directoryPath, file)
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:     ## I would like to write all the filepaths to outfile 
            outfile.write(joined)
```

Comment: forgot to add variable for writing the new file  ```filename = 'outfile.txt' ```

Comment: `w` replaces the file at every iteration, use `open(filename, 'a')`, `a` stands for append, you are only getting the last path because the file is rewritten in every iteration

Comment: however, it now writes all the filepaths as one single string, which is very messy. How can I directly write them with an added space or ```\n``` between each filepath to the file ?

Comment: `joined = os.path.join(directoryPath, file)+'\n'` :)

Comment: take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html might be of use if you work often with paths

Comment: I sometimes do not realise how simple the solutions can be haha... Thanks a lot. Will have a look at the docs. Happy Pythoning! :)